# I want to run a basic Windows guest on OSX with Vagrant, but I keep getting authentication failures

Tags: windows, macos, vagrant

I'm trying to run a Windows 10 guest on an OSX host.

I've installed the latest versions of Vagrant, VirtualBox. I set up a very basic Vagrantfile as follows:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "Microsoft/EdgeOnWindows10"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.0"
end
```

When I try to start Vagrant by executing "vagrant up", I get the following console output which ends with a neverending series of Authentication failure error messages.

```
TCR-C02X29QPJHC9:automation salimfadhley$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'Microsoft/EdgeOnWindows10'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'Microsoft/EdgeOnWindows10' version '1.0' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: automation_default_1548152471264_36082
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

I don't need Edge - I just need Windows and possibly some dot-Net runtimes. I'd like to get started by getting any Windows image up and running.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to use the following in your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
```

This option is described [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html#config-vm-communicator), and you can further configure `winrm` with the settings listed [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/winrm_settings.html).